# Listview fastScrollEnabled thumb not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ListView with fastScrollEnabled that used to be in a ListActivity and worked just fine.

Now I have noticed that the same list in a ListFragment using the compatibility library will scroll the list fast if dragged, but when you touch the thumb icon on the right the list is not moved. This happens on the phone with Gingerbread

When the same fragment is shown on a tablet with Honeycomb the thumb icon never even shows up.

Is this a bug or do I need to do some additional stuff to have this work with fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of comparisons with other list views that are working in my app I found the issue, although I would say that is a framework bug.

I had the line

```
 getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Once I removed that it works just fine..